# Does create2 increase the nonce of the computed contract’s deployment address?

Tags: eip, create2

Simple question about `create2` failure.

Does `create2` increase the nonce of the computed contract’s deployment address ? Or does the first nonce increment operation happens after the first call to the deployed address ?

Comment: I would like a code reference from an actual implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both CREATE and CREATE2 opcodes execute the same [create](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/vm/evm.go#L408-L482) in geth.

Following [EIP158](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-158) the nonce is set to 1 before executing the constructor.

```
if evm.chainRules.IsEIP158 {
    evm.StateDB.SetNonce(address, 1)
}

...

ret, err := run(evm, contract, nil, false)
```